# How to configure OCSP Stapling on Apache 2.4 on Windows?

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-server-2012-r2, openssl

I'm using Apache 2.4.18 and OpenSSL 1.0.1e.
According with https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

Into sugested configuration I received it, but I don't know how to configure it on Windows because I'm not sure about param SSLStaplingCache, is it a directory?

```
# OCSP Stapling, only in httpd 2.3.3 and later
SSLUseStapling          on
SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
SSLStaplingCache        shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, when using the "shmcb" cache for [`UseStaplingCache`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncache), that is a file.  Apache uses that file to naming a shared memory segment, which is shared among threads/processes.  You simply need to make sure that the folders for that file exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
# your server config stuff
# OCSP stapling 1 of 2 (inside your vHost)
SSLUseStapling on
</VirtualHost>

# OCSP stapling 2 of 2 (outside your vHost)
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:C:/Windows/Temp/OCSPstapling_cache(128000)
```